# give an example using GrpcHook and GrpcOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, airflow, grpc

i am new in airflow and gRPC

i use airflow running in docker with default setting

> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

when i try to do in this link

> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-grpc/stable/_api/airflow/providers/grpc/index.html

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
number = calculator_pb2.Number(value=25)

con = GrpcHook(grpc_conn_id='grpc_con',
                       interceptors=[UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor]
        )

run = GrpcOperator(task_id='square_root',
                             stub_class=calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel),
                             call_func='SquareRoot',
                             grpc_conn_id='grpc_con',
                             data=number,
                             log_response=True,
                             interceptors=[UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor]
        )




no response in DAG log even server is shut down or server port is wrong, but it works if i call with simple client
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete dag code? It's not clear what you want to do. GrpcOperator calls a gRPC endpoint to execute an action. Why did you initialize a hook if you don't use it?

Comment: i want to try library gRPC in airflow, my DAG is just that, i just want to see response server with GrpcOperator and GrpcHook in airflow

Comment: The hook needs to be used with in PythonOperator (for example) for what you described you don't really need it. However I don't understand where are you stuck? What is not working?

Comment: i dont get response from GrpcOperator, when i use simple client i got value 5 so i think something wrong with my GrpcOperator

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for I guess is the `GrpcOperator` example.

In your example, the wrong parameter is `data`.

The data parameter should be `data={'request':calculator_pb2.Number(value=25)}`, if you don't modify generated protof files.

This is an example.

```py
from airflow.providers.grpc.operators.grpc import GrpcOperator

from some_pb2_grpc import SomeStub
from some_pb2 import SomeRequest


GrpcOperator(task_id="task_id", stub_class=SomeStub, call_func='Function', data={'request': SomeRequest(var='data')})
```